# Set cloud build default substitution variables through a shell script

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I have shell script that I use in order to be able to create my resources on Google Cloud Platform.

It looks something like this:

```
REGION=us-east1

# Create buckets
FILES_SOURCE=${DEVSHELL_PROJECT_ID}-source-$(date +%s)
gsutil mb -c regional -l ${REGION} gs://${FILES_SOURCE}

FUNCTIONS_BUCKET=${DEVSHELL_PROJECT_ID}-functions-$(date +%s)
gsutil mb -c regional -l ${REGION} gs://${FUNCTIONS_BUCKET}
```

I also have a [Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build) enabled for my project with a trigger defined inside of it. Some of the values for my substitution variables should be equal to **FILES_SOURCE** and **FUNCTIONS_BUCKET** from the script above. If I have my Cloud Build enabled prior to the execution of my shell script, is it possible to somehow assign those values (and their keys) from the shell script?

I can see that we have [gcloud builds](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/builds) interface but it doesn't seem to have such options.

Answer (score 1):

You must be referring to user-defined substitution variables because default substitutions are automatically defined to you by Cloud Build. With regards to `gcloud builds` interface, you can set [`--substitutions`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/builds/submit#--substitutions) flag to specify your user-defined variables but looking at your example, it seems that those aren't fixed.

Unfortunately you won't be able to specify user-defined substitution variables if the values came from a shell script. However, there's a workaround so that your shell script variables will persist the entire build steps by saving the values on a file and then read it as you require.

You've not specified how you intend to use the variables but here's an example:

**build.sh**

```
REGION=us-east1
DEVSHELL_PROJECT_ID=sample-proj

FUNCTIONS_BUCKET=${DEVSHELL_PROJECT_ID}-functions-$(date +%s)
FILES_SOURCE=${DEVSHELL_PROJECT_ID}-source-$(date +%s)

# Store variables on a file
echo $FUNCTIONS_BUCKET > /workspace/functions-bucket &&
echo $FILES_SOURCE > /workspace/files-source
echo "Saved values."
```

**cloudbuild.yaml**

```
steps:

- id: "Read script and store values"
  name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args: ['./build.sh']

- id: "Read Values"
  name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args:
    - -c
    - |
      # Read from "/workspace"
      echo "First we saved " $(cat /workspace/functions-bucket) &&
      echo "Then we saved " $(cat /workspace/files-source)
```

> Note: We used `/workspace` because Cloud Build uses it as a working directory by default.

Reference: https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-pass-data-between-cloud-build-steps-de5c9ebc4cdd

Answer (score 0):

You can't override the substitution variables during the Cloud Build process. So, you have 2 solutions

- Either you work with "Linux" variable, and the answer of Donnald is the right solution (you have to read the value from file in each step and then use it)
- Or you can call a Cloud Build in Cloud Build. Like this

Create the Cloud Build file for your core build, with substitution variables

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args:
      - -c
      - |
        echo $_FUNCTIONS_BUCKET
        echo $_FILES_SOURCE
...
substitutions:
  _FUNCTIONS_BUCKET:
  _FILES_SOURCE:
```

Then, Create a the file for initialization: `cloudbuild-init.yaml`

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args:
      - -c
      - |
          REGION=us-east1
          DEVSHELL_PROJECT_ID=sample-proj

          FUNCTIONS_BUCKET=$${DEVSHELL_PROJECT_ID}-functions-$$(date +%s)
          FILES_SOURCE=$${DEVSHELL_PROJECT_ID}-source-$$(date +%s)

          gcloud builds submit --async --substitutions=_FUNCTIONS_BUCKET=$${FUNCTIONS_BUCKET},_FILES_SOURCE=$${FILES_SOURCE}
```

You can note the async to not wait the end of the underlying Cloud Build before finishing the init one. Else you will pay twice the cost of the Build. On the other hand, you won't know in the trigger if your job worked or not.

It's matter of tradeoffs here.